# Как вывести на экран каждую вторую букву слова? (java)

Tags: java, строки

Как вывести на экран каждую вторую букву любого слова?

Comment: а что у вас не получается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все просто. Используйте функцию `chatAt(int index)`, которая позволит найти символ по номеру. Не забывайте, что нумерация начинается с нуля.

```
String word = "Michael";
for(int i = 0; i < word.length() - 1; i++) {
    if ((i + 1) % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println(word.charAt(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но как сделать чтоб оно само вычислило размер строки и выписало каждую вторую букву?

Comment: @PavelSamsonenka проверяйте

Comment: Работает.  @michael_best спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @PavelSamsonenka и вам спасибо)